# how to pass onvif profile S

Tags: onvif

Our product have passed all mandatory features  of Profile S T ，but we cant get the DOC  and FeatureList .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ugBf.png)
Looks like the profile S and  profile T had  passed.  I Click the " Generate  Doc With Errata"  and then heres's what I got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZKCL.png)
So What can I do to get  the right DOC and FeatureList ?

Comment: you cannot generate the DoC because you failed 55 test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the optional features (when it queries the services during the "DEFINE FEATURES" step as not supported so they don't get tested and failed.

Also the failed features you have shown are required by profile S. Basic notification interface is required by profile S devices, it's optional just for clients.